# Postgres-XL: functions for JSON

Tags: database, relational-database, postgresql-9.2

As it stated, Postgres-XL is based on PostgreSQL 9.2 and it should have json data type.

Is there any way to use functions for json datatype as in Postgresql 9.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily.

You could probably backport the patch series that added json functions to PostgreSQL 9.3, but some understanding of PostgreSQL's source code and structure would be required, as well as some C programming knowledge.

An alternative would be to [hire someone to assist with backporting; see the support page](http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/).

Answer (score 0):

With the current Postgres-XL (9.5) you have full JSON and JSONB function support.